# Java/ Taking method without specify its parameters

Tags: java, reflection

Is there any way to take a method using reflection without specifying its parameters?

I tried this:

```
method = className.class.getMethod("nameOfTheMethod");
```

Where `nameOfTheMethod` is a function with 5 parameters.

But it thinks that `nameOfTheMethod` is a function without parameters, and gives me `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`.

Comment: You need to specify the data types of your parameters in an array and pass it to `getMethod(...)` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all methods

> declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object.

with

```
Method[] methods = ClassName.class.getDeclaredMethods();
```

Iterate through them and find yours. This isn't safe if your method is overloaded as you will still have to check the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that, the `getMethod` needs the number of parameters.

What you could use is `getMethods` or `getDeclaredMethods`, depending what you're looking for, and match any of them with the name you want.

You could get more than 1 of them matching the name but with different parameters.

`getMethods` will

> Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the public member methods of the class or interface represented by this Class object, including those declared by the class or interface and those inherited from superclasses and superinterfaces

while `getDeclaredMethods` will

> Returns an array of Method objects reflecting all the methods declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, but excludes inherited methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `getDeclaredMethods()` and iterating the returned array.

```
    Method[] methods = className.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : methods) {
        if (m.getName().equals("nameOfTheMethod")) {
            // found
            break;
        }
    }
```

This way has the downside, that it only works reliable for not overloaded methods. However, you can easily take this further, so an array or set of all methods with the specified name is found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Parameter types

Try

```
Class[] cArg = new Class[5];
cArg[0] = Long.class;
cArg[1] = Long.class;
cArg[2] = Long.class;
cArg[3] = Long.class;
cArg[4] = Long.class;
Method lMethod = c.getMethod("nameOfMethod", cArg);
```

Replace the longs with whatever type your parameters are of respectively.